# How to wait code on the page with JSOUP? I have 503 error with Bot detection

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, bots, steam

I try parse HTML code from here: [https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2&search_item=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&sort=lh](https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2&search_item=SSG%2008%20%7C%20DARK%20WATER%20%28Field-Tested%29&sort=lh)

But the site Opskins.com has protection "Bot detection", when you firstly visit site - you should wait about 5 seconds and then you will be redirect or reload to right page, that I need.

**How to wait this 5 seconds or some HTML code on this page?**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://opskins.com" + url)
            .header("authority", "opskins.com")
            .header("method", "GET")
            .header("path", url)
            .header("scheme", "https")
            //до сюда с двоеточниями запросы
            .header("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
            .header("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br")
            .header("accept-language", "ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6")
            .header("cache-control", "max-age=0")
            //.header("cookie", "__cfduid=d76231c8cccdbd5303a7d4feeb3f3a11f1466541718; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1292204706.1466541721; request_method=POST; _session_id=5dc49c7814d5087ac51f9d9da20b2680")
            .cookie("steamLogin", "76561198065140894%7C%7C0C35CE73983BCA63E456B6A4831DD772D095AE77")
            .cookie("steamLoginSecure", "76561198065140894%7C%7CCC21BEC8A5E8AD53E9C7086E51BDB8CE407C100A")
            .cookie("steamMachineAuth76561198065140894", "8857F82DB9960F7B66F7842B5F880229A9AF63AB")
            .header("dnt", "1")
            .header("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
            //.header("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")

            .followRedirects(true)
            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
            //.timeout(5000)
            .get();
```

With code above I could take HTML code of page Bot detection.

Comment: When I used selenium driver. I had next JAVA code: `public boolean isWaitGood(By element) {
  try {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
    return true;
    } catch(NoAlertPresentException ex) {
     return false;
     }
   }`
and execute it: 
`if (isWaitGood(By.cssSelector("div.item-amount"))) {
   StringPrice = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.item-amount")).getText();  
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I did some homework for your problem, even if I could not give you one simple solution. Careful observation helped me to figure out somewhat smarter solution.
Below is the code which helps you to pass through the bot.

```
public class BotDetection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2&search_item=SSG%2008%20%7C%20DARK%20WATER%20%28Field-Tested%29&sort=lh")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0").ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();

        /**
         * I'm interested in these three elements
         *     <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get"> 
         *       <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="53ebdc738d543e1f1fd40f8d4abec414"> 
         *       <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1467568987.973-p8bu/jSSDf"> 
         *       <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"> 
         *      </form> 
         */
        Element elementById = document.getElementById("challenge-form"),jschlchild = elementById.child(0), passChild = elementById.child(1);

        String url = "https://opskins.com".concat(elementById.attr("action")).concat("?")
                .concat(jschlchild.attr("name")).concat("=").concat(jschlchild.attr("value")).concat("&")
                .concat(passChild.attr("name")).concat("=").concat(passChild.attr("value")).concat("&jschl-answer=65");

        document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0").ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();

        //Bingo You are done.
        System.out.println(document.body());
    }
```

It worked for me even if I didn't pass jschl-answer=65.

Comment: Your code open main page. http://opskins.com I can open it without problem. I need open this: [https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2&search_item=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&min=&max=&sort=lh&stat=&grade=&exterior=&type=](https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2&search_item=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&min=&max=&sort=lh&stat=&grade=&exterior=&type=)